# Running simple Data Flow import profile deletes records

Tags: import, csv, dataflow, flat-catalog

I encountered a very weird issue. I am trying to run a very basic import data flow profile (done it a hundred times before) by using selected Magento columns: sku, category_ids and status which looks like this:

[image]

My csv file looks basic too:

> sku,category_ids, status <-- column headers
>
> 100001, "10, 11, 12", ENABLED
>
> 100002, "10, 11, 14", ENABLED
>
> 100003, "10, 11, 15", ENABLED

I also tried using '1' for status:

> sku,category_ids, status <-- column headers
>
> 100001, "10, 11, 12", 1
>
> 100002, "10, 11, 14", 1
>
> 100003, "10, 11, 15", 1

The run gives a success message (100% imported) but when looking up the item in backend **Catalog -> Manage Products** I am unable to find it.

upon further check in Magento's tables I found out that the items exists in table **catalog_product_entity** but its record is clearly deleted from **catalog_product_flat_1** (fyi: in my config settings I have enabled 'Use Flat Catalog Product')

I also tried using only two mapped columns and csv consisting of **sku,category_ids** only, but the same: items is deleted from **catalog_product_flat_1**.

Anyone able to explain this phenomenon? Also: what can I do to get the lost items back to flat catalog?

Thanks a lot